# Domain: webcafe.tech’s server IP address could not be found

Tags: dns, cloudflare, tor

I had purchased the domain "webcafe.tech" from Hostinger and added A record to GCP VM for Wordpress hosting. Earlier it was working fine. I added cloudflare for better security. At that time the site was working properly. But after few days I started getting error :  "webcafe.tech’s server IP address could not be found.". I checked with support team. They updated that DNS propogation was stuck so they have reset it. I waited for 48hrs but for my location it is still not working.

I checked in intoDNS.com and found that it have propagated properly to all regions. But still from my location it is not working, so I tried different location, like mobile or public wifi. But no luck.

Then I tried tor and it is working properly there. Even support person told it is working fine from his location.

I tried using dig, here is the output:

```
C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\bin>dig webcafe.tech +short

C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\bin>dig webcafe.tech

; <<>> DiG 9.17.10 <<>> webcafe.tech
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 26865
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;webcafe.tech.                  IN      A

;; Query time: 2032 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 04 02:37:18 India Standard Time 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41

C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\bin>dig webcafe.tech +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.17.10 <<>> webcafe.tech +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.                       480854  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       480854  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20210315210000 20210302200000 42351 . ads06V0AhKOpuJ6zWLp1gY6wKDCULWzG04I0GBEH6sPJPedI77SVsJ83 bAvoPk4xTDOfNOP/Zjxc8aO2uThv+32YD7ceHvmxUg5BFOWTComjLfXI CXfPETCn0tMSS82QSPPXyBMsv2XLYas21RbReUYjtZoPTk2olimEDJ5q Bxyk7sBDQfsoIJ6F/F0L5BYpAhXJw4EV7/BJaOzzc+fPLLlQK4I5W1j1 12HWtqhg+H1ZVbv2SH2mm2eVVUAJg6sFC/cfiAR9HVWwCf4D4yFgm6+8 Uq+087Mvj4dhLS5tCieniBIwAXVBpF1bUVunSgmfoJ2oBEIvYl9usqWa 4zHe6g==
;; Received 525 bytes from 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) in 45 ms

tech.                   172800  IN      NS      b.nic.tech.
tech.                   172800  IN      NS      e.nic.tech.
tech.                   172800  IN      NS      f.nic.tech.
tech.                   172800  IN      NS      a.nic.tech.
tech.                   86400   IN      DS      50095 8 1 82F72F2462DEE25B99DA2470535AD0A7D131F1EB
tech.                   86400   IN      DS      50095 8 2 83F40D01141484D8F07305E5D2E44AC5663149054C598D6E9D993C66 1686C6EE
tech.                   86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20210316170000 20210303160000 42351 . cAsLi5OXC4/bT/N/x5nu9LWQJIXnSbFkpA8/8V7FxWOYEuNYfJYjVO1Z P8BWT7IB3BKlMaAmGZxQEuQi6Q7plP1n68p+8sDDFdHDzqiy0T7KyZm4 6UScDk3fT3pmGS3nxRl61X67uEaWNy4fmukgkX62xsAdX2Yiq5YubsUq UEQDUpcKBQegnlgr4Hmpm+jhilHLe0mjfhkMXgQaT6mY9HnV8ZUrc1mY Ad9zm/tvj9gBUuEQQqJPTocrftSB3NL9UAJZVf8Ui8oxYdTXR7U0OLzM qfcyaJeSfNMR359kruWgnlcVmXoU+9SFExgCFnv5ahkQrLjAePZ8cVgV PVy+Ow==
;; Received 688 bytes from 192.36.148.17#53(i.root-servers.net) in 196 ms

webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      NS      ns1.dns-parking.com.
webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      NS      ns2.dns-parking.com.
webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      DS      2371 8 2 55F22368BD05B6405E96C3E14D7A4FB138CCBB970D3FB44AEB911BD6 C7EC3104
webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      RRSIG   DS 8 2 3600 20210319200140 20210217140833 21876 tech. eDzK56jI7vgFFD3D+kFyMgcBMDemav4/m47KqAQKj48TkMP6QEYdbIV5 3RzfQ/F6yWmuJ6azb1EyPWjLF4gOOymDjBaaq40jewfL+3HQgSmrs8YM 6G8FSE+IwWpewOj653uevU/gCTIacVp38BFgPNUMPT1RRXaqQjIyRZ/d b7A=
;; Received 304 bytes from 212.18.248.60#53(e.nic.tech) in 179 ms

webcafe.tech.           14400   IN      A       35.239.116.255
;; Received 57 bytes from 162.159.24.201#53(ns1.dns-parking.com) in 71 ms
```

Dig trace is showing result but dig short and nslookup is not working.

Can anyone help me out, how to fix this issue?

Edit:
Added GCP server DNS zone and updated Name servers, but still not working. Here are my records:

[GCP DNS Zone Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAnpC.png)
[Hostinger DNS record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HrJe.png)

```sh
c:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\bin>dig webcafe.tech

; <<>> DiG 9.17.10 <<>> webcafe.tech
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 17639
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;webcafe.tech.                  IN      A

;; Query time: 1512 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 04 15:30:12 India Standard Time 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41


c:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\bin>dig webcafe.tech +short

c:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\bin>dig webcafe.tech +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.17.10 <<>> webcafe.tech +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.                       422973  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       422973  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20210315210000 20210302200000 42351 . ads06V0AhKOpuJ6zWLp1gY6wKDCULWzG04I0GBEH6sPJPedI77SVsJ83 bAvoPk4xTDOfNOP/Zjxc8aO2uThv+32YD7ceHvmxUg5BFOWTComjLfXI CXfPETCn0tMSS82QSPPXyBMsv2XLYas21RbReUYjtZoPTk2olimEDJ5q Bxyk7sBDQfsoIJ6F/F0L5BYpAhXJw4EV7/BJaOzzc+fPLLlQK4I5W1j1 12HWtqhg+H1ZVbv2SH2mm2eVVUAJg6sFC/cfiAR9HVWwCf4D4yFgm6+8 Uq+087Mvj4dhLS5tCieniBIwAXVBpF1bUVunSgmfoJ2oBEIvYl9usqWa 4zHe6g==
;; Received 525 bytes from 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) in 85 ms

tech.                   172800  IN      NS      a.nic.tech.
tech.                   172800  IN      NS      b.nic.tech.
tech.                   172800  IN      NS      e.nic.tech.
tech.                   172800  IN      NS      f.nic.tech.
tech.                   86400   IN      DS      50095 8 1 82F72F2462DEE25B99DA2470535AD0A7D131F1EB
tech.                   86400   IN      DS      50095 8 2 83F40D01141484D8F07305E5D2E44AC5663149054C598D6E9D993C66 1686C6EE
tech.                   86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20210317050000 20210304040000 42351 . Z8gH+XbVqLv6fagaF75qhHai+D+XVRfWkFECeZ2MS+SMBq47f91Fr/Ez +6wqNUozI4m2GbOpZ/uPhChz6ekikdlXIGTEQnq2aMVUsnY90xXSd4Vr j8fYHqnEpTDn1Z8GxZeBUneDDcygn7EIks2uaXfvHYsh4zhrucpAPUZW +JGLGtnKegTGCwmHpEle9Ho5RaXqJOMO1CO6Rj+5cWoHHMUjn3MLMwtR LiEL83l5mAqcj3Rwb7utj7SfXWTf5NbioLHONkkTv9cKvHDgDDPcmHHc CimyHoYbnL4/lsTw6pnZekWNntXWuGrK7GOW1WpOQysz9onIdqVdT+o7 8LMu7w==
;; Received 656 bytes from 198.97.190.53#53(h.root-servers.net) in 216 ms

webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      NS      ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      NS      ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      NS      ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      NS      ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.
webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      DS      2371 8 2 55F22368BD05B6405E96C3E14D7A4FB138CCBB970D3FB44AEB911BD6 C7EC3104
webcafe.tech.           3600    IN      RRSIG   DS 8 2 3600 20210319200140 20210217140833 21876 tech. eDzK56jI7vgFFD3D+kFyMgcBMDemav4/m47KqAQKj48TkMP6QEYdbIV5 3RzfQ/F6yWmuJ6azb1EyPWjLF4gOOymDjBaaq40jewfL+3HQgSmrs8YM 6G8FSE+IwWpewOj653uevU/gCTIacVp38BFgPNUMPT1RRXaqQjIyRZ/d b7A=
;; Received 374 bytes from 194.169.218.60#53(a.nic.tech) in 181 ms

webcafe.tech.           300     IN      A       35.239.116.255
;; Received 57 bytes from 216.239.38.108#53(ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com) in 103 ms
```

Comment: Your name servers are on `dns-parking.com`. That is probably not correct. Have you setup name servers? If yes, with who and with what records?

Comment: I had purchased the domain from hostinger, and ns1.dns-parking.com is their nameservers. I have updated new nameservers from google cloud as well, but it is still not working. Here are the Hostinger and GCP zone records.

[GCP zone records:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAnpC.png)
[Hostinger DNS records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HrJe.png)

Comment: What is the configuration at CloudFlare? Does your website have SSL correctly setup?

Comment: I have removed all the configuration from cloudFlare. Even removed the SSL as well to try it, but it not working. In tor it is working fine but in normal browser it not even getting any response. I checked result in https://cachecheck.opendns.com and it shows SERVFAIL in all regions.

Comment: I do not see a problem with your site at this time from my location or with this testing site: https://dnschecker.org/. Edit your question with the problem that you currently have and not what the past problem was. Your SOA TTL is 6 hours. That means that name server changes will take around six hours before downstream resolvers will refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Currently for `webcafe.tech` resolves only with nameservers `ns-cloud-c[1-3].googledomains.com` and `ns[1-2].dns-parking.com`. Al other servers that I tried return `SERVFAIL` what means that the server isn't able to answer properly for some reason.

Let's take a look at `SOA` record

```
>host -t soa webcafe.tech NS-CLOUD-C2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
Using domain server:
Name: NS-CLOUD-C2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
Address: 216.239.34.108#53
Aliases: 

webcafe.tech has SOA record ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300
> host  -t soa webcafe.tech ns1.dns-parking.com
Using domain server:
Name: ns1.dns-parking.com
Address: 162.159.24.201#53
Aliases: 

webcafe.tech has SOA record ns1.dns-parking.com. dns.hostinger.com. 2021030401 10000 2400 604800 3600
```

`dns-parking.com` still consider their servers as masters for your domain.
Also `serial` field in google servers is `21600` and for dns-parking.com it is `2021030401`.

I'd recommend to change `serial` in googledomains.com to some number bigger than `2021030401`. If problem persists, contact hostinger support.

Comment: 1) Your answer include querying `ns1.dns-parking.com`. That server is not (no longer) an authoritative name server, so its response does not matter and is not a problem. 2) The SOA serial number has nothing to do with this problem. Users cannot request that field to be changed. That field is used for synchronizing secondary name servers with the primary. 3) The Google name servers 1-4 report correctly. 4) I am not sure where you got the Google SOA serial being 21600. That value is the TTL (refresh).

Comment: 5) Most likely the OP fiddled with name server entries and created bad records that resulted in SERVFAIL which are cached. The OP will just have to wait out the DNS propagation delay.

Comment: @JohnHanley 1) I explicitly  mentioned that `ns1.dns-parking.com` does not with `SERVEFAIL`. If two  DNS servers give 2 different results for the same domain, this __is__ a problem. 2) On the first OP's picture is clearly seen that users __can__ edit SOA record at googledns.com. 4) You are right, that serial is `1`. 5) This question is ~85000 sec. old.

Comment: Actually I was in the assumption that it is due to DNS propagation delay, and waited for around 5-6 days, still no result. Also, in some regions it is working. One of my friend is in Germany and she is able to access the website. But from India, and other cities in India, we are not able to view it.

Comment: I checked with the support team and found that DNSSEC was enabled on their end. He then disabled it from their end, which helped me resolve this issue. 

Thank you all for your support :-)